# Проблема со скриптом для формы обратной связи

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, form

Делаю форму обратной связи, сам скрипт и обработчик для формы нашел на просторах интернета. Вот они:

```js
<script>
            // этот участок кода нужен только для отображения гифки
            // которая даёт пользователю понять, что что-то происходит
            // и нужно подождать
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                    // найдем элемент с изображением загрузки и уберем невидимость:
                    var imgObj = $("#load-indicator");
                    imgObj.show();
                    // вычислим в какие координаты нужно поместить изображение загрузки,
                    // чтобы оно оказалось в серидине страницы:
                    var centerY = $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() + imgObj.height()) / 2;
                    var centerX = $(window).scrollLeft() + ($(window).width() + imgObj.width()) / 2;
                    imgObj.offset({
                        left: centerX,
                        top: centerY
                    });
                });
                //скрываем изображение после окончания AJAX-запроса
                $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                    $('#load-indicator').hide();
                });
            });
 
            // назначаем действие на такое событие как отправка формы
            $('#feedback').submit(function (evtObj) {
                evtObj.preventDefault();
                // Если элемент формы fileforsending содержит значения (т.е. выбран файл для отправки),
                // то вместо AJAX-запроса используем FormData()
                // поскольку файлы через AJAX-запросы не передаются                
 
                if (document.getElementById("feedback").fileforsending.value !== '') {
                    //показываем гифку ожидания
                    var imgObj = $("#load-indicator");
                    imgObj.show();
                    var centerY = $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() + imgObj.height()) / 2;
                    var centerX = $(window).scrollLeft() + ($(window).width() + imgObj.width()) / 2;
                    imgObj.offset({
                        left: centerX,
                        top: centerY
                    });
                    // этот кусок кода я спёр отсюда http://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/40698-ajax-i-otpravka-fajjlov-s-formy.html
                    var form = document.forms.feedback;
                    var formData = new FormData(form);
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", "mails_sender.php");
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                                data = xhr.responseText;
                                $("#result").html('Результат выполнения: ' + data);
                                // Письмо отправлено, сбрасываем данные формы если прошло успешно
                                if (data === 'Отправлено письмо с вложениями.') {
                                    document.getElementById("feedback").reset();
                                }
                                //убираем гифку ожидания
                                $('#load-indicator').hide();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send(formData);
                    // В противном случае (не прикреплён файл для отправки)
                    // Делаем AJAX-запрос для отправки письма
                } else {
                    var form = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        // Здесь файл, который обрабатывает полученные от пользователя данные и отправляет почту
                        url: 'mails_sender.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        // Действия в случае успешной отправки AJAX-запроса (а не письма!)
                        // Здесь data - полученное от mails_sender.php сообщение
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data === 'Отправлено письмо без вложений.') {
                                $("#result").html('Отправлено письмо без вложений.');
                                // Письмо отправлено, сбрасываем данные формы
                                document.getElementById("feedback").reset();
                                // Следующая строка после успешной отправки сообщения
                                // перенаправляет пользователь на любую страницу/сайт
                                // достаточно раскомментировать её и поменять адрес сайта webware.biz
                                // на ваш собственный
                                //document.location.href = 'http://webware.biz';
                            } else {
                                $("#result").html(data);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            $("#result").html('Результат выполнения: ' + data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
```

```html
        <div style="color: red;" id="result">some text</div><br />
        <img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="load-indicator" alt="loading" style="position:absolute; z-index:1000; display:none;" />
 
        <h2>Форма обратной связи</h2>
        <form method="post" action="mails_sender.php" id="feedback" name="feedback" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 146px">Ваш e-mail</td>
                    <td><input name="youremail" type="text" style="width: 440px" size="20" /></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 146px">Тема сообщения</td>
                    <td><input name="subject" type="text" style="width: 440px" size="20" /></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Телефон:</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" style="width: 440px" size="20">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 146px">Ваше сообщение</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="message" style="width: 440px; height: 130px" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 146px">Ваше имя</td>
                    <td><input name="name" type="text" style="width: 440px" size="20" value="" /></td></tr>
 
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 146px">Вы можете присоединить необходимые файлы</td>
                    <td><input name="fileforsending" type="file" style="width: 440px" /></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 146px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><br />
                        <input name="Reset1" type="reset" value="Очистить" style="width: 97px" />
                        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Отправить" style="width: 157px" />
                            &nbsp; </span>
                    </td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Но проблема вот в чем в скрипте для отправки формы используется идентификатор формы, а их на странице предполагается быть несколько пусть и абсолютно одинаковых, а так как идентификатор должен быть только один данные будут отправляться только с одной формы.

Попытался заменить конструкцию `document.getElementById(feedback)` на такую `document.getElementsByClassName(feedback)` но ничего не получилось полагаю из за вот этой строки `var form = document.forms.feedback;` В ней переменной form присваиваются какие то функции, но к сожалению не могу понять какие и за что это отвечает.

одскажите как можно модифицировать скрипт чтобы можно было отправлять данные с любой формы на странице?

Comment: Не понятно про дублирующие формы. Можно более развернуто? Возможно вопрос в корректировке построения страницы.

Comment: Про document.getElementsByClassName(feedback). 1) feedback - это переменная? Если нет, то document.getElementsByClassName("feedback"). 2) Не вижу в коде элементов с атрибутом class="feedback". И вообще в коде данный атрибут не используется.

Comment: var form = document.forms.feedback; //Переменной form  присваивается объект form с атрибутом name="feedback"

Comment: @DanIrkutskiy В общем на одной странице есть несколько одинаковых форм в разных местах, и все они не могу быть с одним идентификатором, это же запрещается спецификацией.

Comment: @DanIrkutskiy я видимо удалил класс feedback из кода (он должен быть присвоен самой форме), попробую с протестировать с вашей подсказкой. И последнее если заменить document.getElementById(feedback) на document.getElementsByClassName("feedback") не вызовет ли это ошибку вот здесь - var form = document.forms.feedback; ???

Comment: Я не предлагал менять getElementById на getElementsByClassName. id и class разные атрибуты. Я предлагал использовать не переменную feedback, а значение "feedback". Т.к. переменная feedback не объявлена. А var form = document.forms.feedback - присваивает переменной form ссылку на объект в атрибутом name равным "feedback".

Comment: Кстати обращаю внимание, что $('#feedback').submit(function (evtObj) - присваивает функцию срабатыванию события submit только для формы с id="feedback".